# Difference between Halfway through/toward/to

Tags: grammar

I still do not understand the differences between the two words mentioned above. I looked at both Oxford and Cambridge dictionary for some extra information.

Besides, is there any difference with the word In the middle?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Say you are moving through a tunnel and you are half way.

You are 'half way through the tunnel'

You are also half way to the end of the tunnel.

You are travelling towards the end of the tunnel

You are half way on your journey as you travel towards the tunnel exit.

Hope this helps.